# Python, to calculate difference of coordinates in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

An existing function to calculate 2 coordinates. for example, it can calculate the distance between this 2 cities (52.22, 21.01) and (52.40, 16.92).

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def cor_dist_calculator(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
    R = 6373.0
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c
    print "Distance is: "  + str(distance) + " km."
    return

# to calcualte distance between (52.22, 21.01) and (52.40, 16.92)
cor_dist_calculator(radians(52.22), radians(52.40), radians(21.01), radians(16.92))
```

The output is:

```
Distance is: 278.82127298 km.
```

Now for a list of cities, I want to calculate the distances between any 2 of them. The data comes in a dictionary form, and I can access the coordinates:

```
cities = {
"Ahmedabad":"23.02579,72.58727",
"Bengaluru":"12.97194,77.59369",
"Chennai":"13.08784,80.27847",
"Delhi":"28.65195,77.23149",
"Hyderabad":"17.38405,78.45636",
"Kanpur":"26.46523,80.34975",
"Kolkata":"22.56263,88.36304",
"Mumbai":"19.07283,72.88261",
"Pune":"18.51957,73.85535",
"Surat":"21.19594,72.83023"}

for c, o in cities.items():
    lat = o.split(",")[0]
    lon = o.split(",")[1]
```

How can I calculate all the distances between any 2 cities in the dictionary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
import json

def cor_dist_calculator(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):
    R = 6373.0
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = R * c
    return distance # Change to return result instead of printing

cities = {
  "Ahmedabad":"23.02579,72.58727",
  "Bengaluru":"12.97194,77.59369",
  "Chennai":"13.08784,80.27847",
  "Delhi":"28.65195,77.23149",
  "Hyderabad":"17.38405,78.45636",
  "Kanpur":"26.46523,80.34975",
  "Kolkata":"22.56263,88.36304",
  "Mumbai":"19.07283,72.88261",
  "Pune":"18.51957,73.85535",
  "Surat":"21.19594,72.83023"
}

result = { } # result cache

for c1, o1 in cities.items():
  for c2, o2 in cities.items():
    if c1 == c2: # Skip distance to itself
      continue
    if c1 not in result:
      result[c1] = {}
    if c2 not in result:
      result[c2] = {}
    if c2 in result[c1]: # Skip calculation if result exists
      continue
    lat1, lon1 = o1.split(",")
    lat2, lon2 = o2.split(",")
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = float(lat1), float(lon1), float(lat2), float(lon2)
    dist = cor_dist_calculator(radians(lat1), radians(lat2), radians(lon1), radians(lon2))
    result[c1][c2] = dist
    result[c2][c1] = dist

# Use JSON to pretty print
print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Ahmedabad": {
        "Bengaluru": 1236.9685147466164,
        "Chennai": 1371.5560941922058,
        "Delhi": 779.3993196898124,
        "Hyderabad": 876.7339794841921,
        "Kanpur": 872.2163865213793,
        "Kolkata": 1617.7373028708505,
        "Mumbai": 440.75405570398016,
        "Pune": 518.2729673252524,
        "Surat": 205.06784688939214
    },
    "Bengaluru": {
        "Ahmedabad": 1236.9685147466164,
        "Chennai": 291.2228040150677,
        "Delhi": 1744.487772289504,
        "Hyderabad": 499.41428330226853,
        "Kanpur": 1528.1728332155533,
        "Kolkata": 1560.4315624298629,
        "Mumbai": 844.9020405056748,
        "Pune": 735.3744543489997,
        "Surat": 1045.3221688709566
    },
    "Chennai": {
        "Ahmedabad": 1371.5560941922058,
        "Bengaluru": 291.2228040150677,
        "Delhi": 1759.6662314194639,
        "Hyderabad": 516.3080888651748,
        "Kanpur": 1487.983445250212,
        "Kolkata": 1356.9170709394425,
        "Mumbai": 1033.058314823502,
        "Pune": 914.9401253270859,
        "Surat": 1199.443950315355
    },
    "Delhi": {
        "Ahmedabad": 779.3993196898124,
        "Bengaluru": 1744.487772289504,
        "Chennai": 1759.6662314194639,
        "Hyderabad": 1259.5527686310922,
        "Kanpur": 392.0259915147513,
        "Kolkata": 1304.8787459771033,
        "Mumbai": 1153.348591508457,
        "Pune": 1178.1906584531494,
        "Surat": 940.4321887894869
    },
    "Hyderabad": {
        "Ahmedabad": 876.7339794841921,
        "Bengaluru": 499.41428330226853,
        "Chennai": 516.3080888651748,
        "Delhi": 1259.5527686310922,
        "Kanpur": 1028.7605594631257,
        "Kolkata": 1184.4860919672817,
        "Mumbai": 618.0416762200242,
        "Pune": 502.9490477553323,
        "Surat": 726.9427844409639
    },
    "Kanpur": {
        "Ahmedabad": 872.2163865213793,
        "Bengaluru": 1528.1728332155533,
        "Chennai": 1487.983445250212,
        "Delhi": 392.0259915147513,
        "Hyderabad": 1028.7605594631257,
        "Kolkata": 919.5167629722739,
        "Mumbai": 1123.0549698313646,
        "Pune": 1106.9736378339578,
        "Surat": 963.370481325532
    },
    "Kolkata": {
        "Ahmedabad": 1617.7373028708505,
        "Bengaluru": 1560.4315624298629,
        "Chennai": 1356.9170709394425,
        "Delhi": 1304.8787459771033,
        "Hyderabad": 1184.4860919672817,
        "Kanpur": 919.5167629722739,
        "Mumbai": 1654.6687139324506,
        "Pune": 1575.6823437947044,
        "Surat": 1609.718084142609
    },
    "Mumbai": {
        "Ahmedabad": 440.75405570398016,
        "Bengaluru": 844.9020405056748,
        "Chennai": 1033.058314823502,
        "Delhi": 1153.348591508457,
        "Hyderabad": 618.0416762200242,
        "Kanpur": 1123.0549698313646,
        "Kolkata": 1654.6687139324506,
        "Pune": 119.49195110246427,
        "Surat": 236.21650702410025
    },
    "Pune": {
        "Ahmedabad": 518.2729673252524,
        "Bengaluru": 735.3744543489997,
        "Chennai": 914.9401253270859,
        "Delhi": 1178.1906584531494,
        "Hyderabad": 502.9490477553323,
        "Kanpur": 1106.9736378339578,
        "Kolkata": 1575.6823437947044,
        "Mumbai": 119.49195110246427,
        "Surat": 316.4157942067634
    },
    "Surat": {
        "Ahmedabad": 205.06784688939214,
        "Bengaluru": 1045.3221688709566,
        "Chennai": 1199.443950315355,
        "Delhi": 940.4321887894869,
        "Hyderabad": 726.9427844409639,
        "Kanpur": 963.370481325532,
        "Kolkata": 1609.718084142609,
        "Mumbai": 236.21650702410025,
        "Pune": 316.4157942067634
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

If user gives two city names as input, you can simply do:

```
def dist_two_cities(city1,city2):
    lat1 = cities[city1].split(",")[0]
    lon1 = cities[city1].split(",")[0]

    lat2 = cities[city2].split(",")[0]
    lon2 = cities[city2].split(",")[0]

    return cor_dist_calculator(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2)
```

And, if you want to calculate randomly for all - you can loop over.

Answer (score 1):

You have already done most of the things.
It is just a matter of taking the input from the user and formatting it as per your needs.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    city1, city2 = input("Enter the name of the city seperated by comma\n").split(',')

    lat1, long1 = cities.get(city1.strip()).split(',')
    lat2, long2 = cities.get(city2.strip()).split(',')

    cor_dist_calculator(radians(float(lat1)), radians(float(lat2)), radians(float(long1)), radians(float(long2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to add this line to the calculator just below the def:

```
lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2 = radians(lat1), radians(lat2), radians(lon1), radians(lon2)
```

So you can easily enter the coordinates in degrees.

Then, build a list with the combinations of two cities (to avoid calculating distance from city to itself or city1-city2 and city2-city1):

```
import itertools
comb_cities = list(itertools.combinations(cities.keys(), 2))

    res = []
for city1, city2 in comb_cities:
  distance = cor_dist_calculator(int(cities[city1][0]),int(cities[city1][1]), int(cities[city2][0]),int(cities[city2][1]) )
  res.append((city1, city2, distance))
```

Now res contains:

```
[('Ahmedabad', 'Bengaluru', 157.22689337854425), ('Ahmedabad', 'Chennai', 248.52555085450666), ('Ahmedabad', 'Delhi', 675.9491465155114), ('Ahmedabad', 'Hyderabad', 675.9491465155114), ......
```

If you want the distance in both directions (which is the same:)) change `itertools.combinations` to `itertools.permutations`.

Using `permutations` you can get the information back like this:

```
city1 = "Surat"
city2 = "Bengaluru"
print ([ cities for cities in res if cities[0] == city1 and cities[1] == city2])
```

Comment: thank you for the help and efforts! your solution is very thoughtful, and benefit lots of people. However the list of cities is very long so the output is very very long, which will be used for an analysis. Another reply is fits my need more. Can I have your kind understanding?